# Group By in SQL with joins

Tags: sql, oracle11g

trying executing this code on the group with joins but its giving me error that its not a group by  statement

code below

```
     SELECT 
        sum (quantity),   
     customers.customer_name,
     states.state_name,       
     regions.region_name

      FROM sales  JOIN customers  ON sales.customer_id = customers.customer_id
join states on customers.state_id = states.state_id 
join regions on states.region_id = regions.region_idhaving sum(quantity) >= 10  


 GROUP BY   sales.sale_id, customers.customer_name, states.state_name, regions.region_id
 ;
```

saying not a group by expression.

Comment: You're grouping by region_id and then selecting region_name

Answer (score 0):

The `having` clause goes after the `group by`.  But you should learn to use table aliases so your queries are easier to write and to read.

In addition, you need `region_name` in the `GROUP BY`:

```
  SELECT sum(quantity), c.customer_name, st.state_name, r.region_name
  FROM sales s JOIN
       customers c
       ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id JOIN
       states st
       ON c.state_id = st.state_id JOIN
       regions r
       ON s.region_id = r.region_id
 GROUP BY s.sale_id, c.customer_name, st.state_name, r.region_name
 HAVING sum(quantity) >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything that you use in your `SELECT` that is not part of aggregate operation (such as `SUM`) needs to be included in your `GROUP BY` statement